# How to have two Columns with same height length

Tags: html

I have two columns, first column has an image, second is the article. The article has a ton of "Empty spaces" I would like the height of the article to be the same height as the image so there's not visible empty space.

```
<article>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-sm-height">
      <aside class="col-sm-6 ">
        <img src="http://i0.wp.com/www.sooziq.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/32.jpg?resize=270%2C200" />
      </aside>
      <aside class="col-sm-6">
        <div>
          <span> <a href="http://www.sooziq.com/category/miscellaneous/" id="A_1">Basketball</a></span>
          <h2 id="H2_2">
                                <a href="http://www.sooziq.com/22045/he-colored-his-phones-camera-the-reason-why-will-amaze-you/" rel="bookmark" id="A_2">What really Matters</a>
                            </h2>
          <span id="SPAN_2">November 12, 2015</span>
          <p>
        Make sure you load up on the fluids and snacks and use the washroom because these are the top 3 things to watch for in basketball! <a href="http://www.sooziq.com/22045/he-colored-his-phones-camera-the-reason-why-will-amaze-you/" id="A_3">Read More</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Demo

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQVxor

I would like it to also be responsive, I can get the height to match using trial and error but I don't think that's the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple and maybe also the best solution in your case is to make the 2 columns' **parent div** have the **same background color** as the 2 columns do so it looks like the article column has expanded.

In your css, find `.row-sm-height` under `@media (min-width: 768px)` and add the background color:

```css
.row-sm-height {
    display:table-row;
    background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

And you just need to **do nothing about specifying any height**. It just adjusts to your image height.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you for making it short and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your images will be the same size one the same device you can set the min-height.

Add a new class to the div that is your article (not the one with "col-x").
Set the class to have a min-height of Npx.

As an example for your CSS:

```
div.image-article {
    min-height: 250px;   
}
```

If making it responsive you probably have your images smaller on different devices. Use a media query for these.

```
div.image-article {
@media (min-width: 0) {
    min-height: 250px;
}
@media (min-width: @screen-xs-min) {
    min-height: 250px;
}
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    min-height: 275px;
}
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    min-height: 290px;
}
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    min-height: 320px;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @VictorySaber, looks like there are some errors in that code.